# How to align nav bar links in a row

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to keep all my links in my nav bar in one line in a row. Here is my CSS and HTML. Thanks

HTML -

```
 <ul class="nav">

    <h3 class="navlogo">LOGO HERE</h3>

         <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Work">Work</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
```

CSS -

```
.nav {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.70;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px 1px 25px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #1C86EE;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

I want the nav bar to be in the center of my page mainly. I also have jquery and bootstrap installed into the page.

Comment: How's this different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574218/how-to-align-text-boxs-in-one-line)?

Comment: I realized my mistake in the last question and was wondering if it is possible to help me with this, cause when I install bootstrap my nav bar becomes vertical but if I uninstall it the bar goes normal.

Comment: Then what you need to do is edit your last question; not repost it as new

Comment: oh ok my bad, won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bootstrap v4, I created [this](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/KWMpvW?editors=1000) demo to hopefully help you.

Using the markup that Bootstrap provides on their Examples page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response! But I tried your code I got this, [Image](http://imgur.com/a/KPwNl)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using Bootstrap

[Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
[Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 0):

with Bootstrap you have to add this in the  section

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/